# Would the circumferential component of a magnetized ring affect the external field?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I understand that if a ring or torus made of some magnetizable material was given a circumferential magnetization, its external field would be zero, or nearly so, as the lines of force within the body of the magnet are always parallel to the ring's outer surface.

If, however, there was some axial component to the field as well, then the lines of force would escape the ring from the top and the bottom.   Would the circumferential component of the ring's magnetization affect the direction of the magnetic field (near the ring, in particular), or would it be indistinguishable from a ring that was merely magnetized along its z axis?  In particular, if you brought something such as a compass needle near the magnet (say one that could orient itself in any direction in 3d, rather than just on a 2d-plane), would its direction point any differently near such a magnet than from being near an otherwise similar ring that had a simple z axis magnetization only? Mathematically (EDIT: or at least geometrically, based on how the lines of force are oriented within the body of such a magnet), it seems at first like it would, but this actually doesn’t make any sense to me if I really think about it some more.

If there would be no external field that a compass could react to if a ring were to have had a purely circumferential magnetization, and it is only the non-circumferential component of the magnetization of the aforementioned ring that allows any magnetic field to escape at all, then why would a compass react to anything but the non-circumferential component?

Comment: *"Mathematically it seams like it would,"* Can you add this mathematical argument? It is not clear what do you mean, and as you seem to think, the conclusion is unlikely. If the field is only inside the ring, it will not affect the compass.

Comment: Mathematically might be the wrong word... "geometrically" might be better.  I mean that since the field inside of a magnet with both circumferential and axial magnetization is hitting the tops and bottoms of the ring at an oblique angle, rather than perpendicular to the top and bottom surfaces (as it would be with a purely axial magnetization), that it intuitively seems like the escaping field may have *some* component that isn't entirely the same as that produced by a purely axially magnetized ring.